# Bootstrap: Toggle expands but cant close

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I don't think my code has any issues but the toggle just doesn't close when I clicked the button or outside the toggle area for some reason. I also tried moving my header code around but still, it did not help. Help! The header part is my setup for my bootstrap and jquery. and the body part is the navbar. thank you in advance.

**Header:**

```
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </e
```

**Body:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand"><img src="~/images/logo.png" /></a>

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsemyNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class=" navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a asp-page="/Example">Example</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Social">Social</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a asp-page="/Dashboard">DASHBOARD</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Logout">LOGOUT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Setting"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with the version of jQuery you us in: `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js`. If you change it to `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` your collapse button will work. So your header will be:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

Comment: The collapse button is still not working. What I did is by taking out <environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment> and it works. But I have no idea why lol